# IIS / AngularJS Single Page Application - How do I prevent page caching of a single index.html when navigating in app

Tags: html, angularjs, caching, single-page-application

I need to make my application (SPA) to not cache index.html across page navigation actions.

My app has cache busting but it is only working when I update (reload) index.html.

How do I force the application not cache the index.html when navigating within my app and reload index.html on each page navigation click or action?

**Here is my existing snippet index.html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" manifest="sw.appcache">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

**sw.appcache file contents**

```
CACHE MANIFEST
NETWORK:
*
```

**Edit:**

The following addition to the script tag within my index.html forces page to reload every time the url changes.

```
 window.onhashchange = function() {
        var parts = window.location.href.split("#");
        window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "?t=" + (new Date()).getTime() + "#" + parts[1];

      }
```

Comment: If you're forcing a page reload on every navigation change, you might as well just use a regular web application instead of bothering with a SPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience with this in PHP is that you cannot ever control whether the browser decides to cache your page or not, despite whatever fancy headers you use.

The best way is to manipulate the URL with the request parameter.

Instead of http://example.com/mypage.html
Use: http://example.com/mypage.html?timestamp

Where timestamp is generated dynamically at runtime, and could be a random number or any dynamically-unique string you wish.

It's also a good trick to prevent browsers from caching CSS, JS, images, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,  the app is purely angular code on my end and therefore I don't think I can inject a timestamp on the request.  Also I am using routes for getting to a page.

Comment: @Vahe No problem. Angular or any other JS can use a window.redirect if you really have to. Another option is to load the resources dynamically (same trick) instead of worrying about loading the entire page as a new request. Good luck in the coding jungle!